# Wordpress function wp_enqueue_style is missing rel parameter

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, polymer

I am trying to build wordpress plugin with polymer at admin side. Polymer use link element to import the library. However wp function "wp_enqueue_style" is missing setting up rel attribute. This is from the official doc ([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)):

> wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );

There is a function named "wp_style_add_data" but I tried to set rel attribute in this way without any luck:

```
wp_enqueue_style('polymer_html', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'../js/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html', array(), '1.0', 'all');
wp_style_add_data('polymer_html', 'rel', 'import'); //this way
wp_style_add_data('polymer_html', 'import', true);  //and also this way
```

Here is example of importing polymer:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

I was developing wp plugins long time ago, so I would appreciate your help to find a best workaround to this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`style_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function( $html, $handle, $href ) {
    if( 'polymer-handle' === $handle )
        $html = str_replace('href=', 'rel="import" href=', $html);
    return $html;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Change `polymer-handle` with the actual handle.